# How to handle collect of flow inside of setOnClickListener method?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

**MainActivity.kt**

```
- - - - - - - - - - EXAMPLE 1 - - - - - - - - - -

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

    val settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel by viewModels()
    activityMainBinding.loadSettingsBtn.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            settingsViewModel.getSettings().collect {
                Log.w("A8452", "MainActivity -> ${it.javaClass.name}")
            }
        }
    }
}

- - - - - - - - - - EXAMPLE 2 - - - - - - - - - -

private var isCollectFired = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(activityMainBinding.root)

    val settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel by viewModels()
    activityMainBinding.loadSettingsBtn.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            if (!isCollectFired) {
                isCollectFired = true
                settingsViewModel.getSettings().collect {
                    Log.w("A8452", "MainActivity -> ${it.javaClass.name}")
                }
            } else
                settingsViewModel.getSettings()
        }
    }
}
```

**SettingsViewModel.kt**

```
- - - - - - - - - - Both examples use the same code in this class - - - - - - - - - -

class SettingsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val mutableStateFlow: MutableStateFlow<ConnectionStatus> = MutableStateFlow(ConnectionStatus.Loading)
    private lateinit var settingsRepository: SettingsRepository

    fun getSettings(): StateFlow<ConnectionStatus> {
        if (!::settingsRepository.isInitialized)
            settingsRepository = SettingsRepository()

        viewModelScope.launch {
            settingsRepository.getSettings().collect {
                Log.w("A8452", "SettingsViewModel -> ${it.javaClass.name}")
                mutableStateFlow.emit(it)
            }
        }

        return mutableStateFlow
    }

}
```

In example 1, when you click the button, it loads settings from the server. However, if you click the button many times, it triggers multiple collects. With each click, the collects grow gradually, similar to a rolling snowball.

For more details about the problem in example 1, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770255/stateflow-collect-multiple-times-inside-each-button-click-event-how-to-).

In example 2, I created a boolean variable called `isCollectFired`. Before firing a collect upon clicking the button, it checks the variable. This resolved the issue, although I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

Now, I'm puzzled because inside `SettingsViewModel`, there is a collect without checks like what I implemented in `MainActivity`. Surprisingly, it doesn't grow gradually like a rolling snowball when the user clicks the button. Can you explain why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea why you want to collect a flow within a button-click event. For me, I didn't used to like this. I separate function and flow, which means the function doesn't need to return the actual flow. Just do its process and emit result from flow. After that, the UI class collects the flow changes. Button click event just call the function.

In viewModel class

```
private val _getReferralCodeFlow: MutableStateFlow<String?> =MutableStateFlow(null)
val getReferralCodeFlow = _getReferralCodeFlow.asStateFlow()

fun getReferralCode() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        runCatching {
            val data = getReferralCode.execute(Unit) // assume string return
            _getReferralCodeFlow.value = data
        }.getOrElse {
            Timber.e(it)
            _getReferralCodeFlow.value = "Error occur"
        }
    }
}
```

Button click in activity or fragment

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.getReferralCode()
}
```

Collect flow in activity or fragment

```
lifecycleScope.launch { 
    viewModel.getReferralCodeFlow.collectLatest { 
        // do something
    }
}
```